# How can I capture audio signal from two channels with QAudioInput

Tags: c++, qt, audio, signals

I want to capture sound  from my audio device with QAudioInput.I have a stereo (Two channels) input signal, normally I just have call  the function setChannelCount() with the number of my channels, in this case 2. my goal is to save the signal from channel1 in file 1 and signal from channel 2 in file 2. my problem is how to separate the both signals.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the documentation of `QAudioInput`, you would need your own specialization of `QIODevice` in which you would override `writeData` in order to fan the data out into 2 files. I haven't tried to compile this but it should give you the general idea.

```
class MyIODevice : public QIODevice
{
public:
    MyIODevice(QIODevice* file1, QIODevice* file2)
      : m_file1(file1), m_file2(file2) {}

    qint64 writeData(const char* data, qint64 maxSize)
    {
        // for 32-bits with the channels interleaved.
        // I'm also making an assumption that QAudioInput will call this with
        // a complete frame of data.
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize / 8; ++i)
        {
            m_file1->writeData(data, 4);
            data += 4;
            m_file2->writeData(data, 4);
            data += 4;
        }
    }
private:
    QIODevice* m_file1;
    QIODevice* m_file2;
};
```

As written this would only work with one audio format but could easily be made more general by passing some parameters about the format to the constructor, etc...

Comment: thanks, but before saving , i would like to process signal 1 from channel 1 and signal 2 from channel 2 in real time,I really one to work with the same audio format but from two channels.so I intend to use two buffer 1 and 2.my problem is I dont known how to separate the both signals  when Ithe function setChannelCount() is called with 2(setChannelCount(2)).how to set or separate  the signals from channel 1 and channel 2.  QAudioformat documentation dont help me

Comment: @TheMan I didn't see your comment sooner, but what you are now asking is a different question from your original post.